# Display markers with criterion from .json file

Tags: json, markers

This is a part of my code to display markers in map :

```
    function refreshMap() {
    if (markerClusterer) {
      markerClusterer.clearMarkers();
    }

    var markers = [];

    var markerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(imageUrl,
      new google.maps.Size(24, 32));

    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.photos[i].latitude,
          data.photos[i].longitude)
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position: latLng,
       draggable: true,
       icon: markerImage
      });
      markers.push(marker);
    }
```

Markers are displayed from a table data.json

all it's working

Now In the properties of markers there is a index containing a number, and I just want display markers containing number 2 or 3 or 5, but not all markers.

It is possible ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few time of work I have found the solution :

```
function refreshMap() {
    if (markerClusterer) {
      markerClusterer.clearMarkers();
    }

    var markers = [];

    var markerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(imageUrl,
      new google.maps.Size(24, 32));

    for (var i = 0; i < 11; ++i) {

    var Indice = data.photos[i].owner_id

    if (Indice == 109117) {

      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.photos[i].latitude,
          data.photos[i].longitude)
```